# Cross-Origin Request Blocked angular JS post request

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I use cordova and angular js.When I try to login my webservice from my app then I get the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the
remote resource at http://devsandipon2.dhaka.vantage.com/webservice.php. This
can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Any one help?

Comment: What is the language of your server? Any framework?

Comment: language of my server is: Php

Comment: Write this before make requests http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html In the same link of @RezaRahmati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable CORS on your site on web server. CORS prevents the other sites or application of accessing your webservices without your permissions.

Take a look at http://enable-cors.org/server.html